# MySQL Errors when attempting to start

Tags: mysql

CentOS 5.8

I ran a yum update and MySQL updated but now it won't start. Any ideas as to what would cause this/how I can fix?

I get the following in the log:

```
121017 15:58:39 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
121017 15:58:40 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121017 15:58:40 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121017 15:58:40 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
121017 15:58:40 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121017 15:58:40 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
121017 15:58:40 InnoDB: Error: Linux Native AIO is not supported on tmpdir.
InnoDB: You can either move tmpdir to a file system that supports native AIO
InnoDB: or you can set innodb_use_native_aio to FALSE to avoid this message.
121017 15:58:40 InnoDB: Error: Linux Native AIO check on tmpdir returned error[22]
121017 15:58:40 InnoDB: Warning: Linux Native AIO disabled.
121017 15:58:40 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 512.0M
121017 15:58:40 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121017 15:58:40 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121017 15:58:41  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121017 15:58:42 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 360826692325
121017 15:58:42 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'record_buffer=2M'
121017 15:58:42 [ERROR] Aborting

121017 15:58:42  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
121017 15:58:42  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 360826692325
121017 15:58:43 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

121017 15:58:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: Do you have a 'record_buffer=2M' in your my.cnf file? Try removing it and seeing if that does the trick.

Comment: i just did that. it starts now. i wonder if i need that setting... thanks.

Comment: Alright, I posted that as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `record_buffer=2M` from your my.cnf file and try again.

Comment: and in response to whether you need it or not... I couldn't find record_buffer in the variables or global variables section of the MySQL docs, so maybe find out who put that config option there and find out what they were trying to do with it.

Comment: Oh, it was there, in pre 5.5 MySQL versions.

Answer (score 3):

Did you upgrade to MySQL 5.5? The variable `record_buffer` is deprecated.

Refer to [What Is New in MySQL 5.5](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/mysql-nutshell.html):

```
 Removed Features
 The record_buffer system variable (use read_buffer_size).
```

The variable is now called [read_buffer_size](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_buffer_size).